# Problem with rc.local to start a script after linux boot

Tags: linux

I made a startup.sh script to start my aplication 10 seconds after the linux boot. The script, startup.sh, works very good, it wait 10 seconds to run my application (terminal). I put the path of this script in the rc.local to start the aplication 10 seconds after linux boot. The path in the rc.local file is:

/home/pi/Desktop/startup.sh &

The problem is that I think that the rc.local doenst work, because the startup.sh is not working.

What I need to do to start the rc.local?

Somebody can help me?

Prof. Wagner

Comment: What does startup.sh contain?

Comment: #!/bin/sh
sleep 10
cd terminal
sudo ./terminal (terminal is the name of my aplication), this startup work very good if I execute of out rc.local....but rclocal do not start to call this startup

Comment: Add the full path to your application, presumably /home/pi/terminal/terminal. rc.local is run as user root not user pi

Comment: or change cd terminal to cd /home/pi/terminal

Comment: You need to explain in more detail exactly what `startup.sh` does as this has consequences when it is run in the context of `rc.local` during boot.

Comment: Check the log file. `cat /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it. You should create a systemd Unit file to start your script. But that wasn't asked.

Comment: I stoped to use /etc/rc.local and now I am to use crontab -e and the result is very stranger: When I run a script in python with no external module, it works very good, I means, after the linux boot this script runs very good, but when I run a script with external module like, Adafruit_CharLCD and others, the script doenst run after linux boot. My problem is I need that scripts run after boot automatic.